# Counterexample - modules over non-Noetherian domain

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Does anyone know an example of a (necessarily non-Noetherian) domain $A$ and a finitely generated $A$-module $M$ with the property that $M_f$ is not free for any nonzero $f \in A$? This would provide a counterexample to a standard algebraic geometry exercise in the non-Noetherian case.

Comment: You mean the following "exercise", right? If $M$ is a sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules locally of finite presentation and $M_x$ is a free $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$-module, then there is an open neighborhood $x \in U \subseteq X$ such that $M|_U$ is free. This doesn't really have to do with noetherian assumption, it works for any ringed space $X$. If $X$ is an integral scheme, then one may take the generic point of $X$. It is essential that $M$ is locally of finite presentation, not just of finite type. Of course your question still makes sense.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Isn't he rather talking about 'generic freeness/flatness'?http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_flatness

Comment: Apply my remark to $X=\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ ...

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg that's right. But now I think $M$ finite type is enough on an integral scheme: see my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually I don't think there are any counterexamples: the proof seems to go through without the Noetherian hypothesis. Let $K$ be the fraction field of $A$ and choose a $K$-basis for $M \otimes_A K$. By clearing denominators we can choose this basis in the image of $M$, so we get a morphism $\varphi : A^{\oplus r} \to M$ which induces an isomorphism $K^{\oplus r} \cong M \otimes_A K$. By exactness of localization it follows that $\text{ker } \varphi$ and $\text{coker } \varphi$ vanish at the generic point, i.e. they are torsion. Since $A$ is a domain $A^{\oplus r}$ is torsion-free, so $\text{ker } \varphi = 0$ already. On the other hand, $\text{coker } \varphi$ is finitely generated because $M$ is, so we can find a nonzero $f \in A$ which annihilates $\text{coker } \varphi$. This is the desired $f$.

Comment: +1. This seems to work. This shows that the full power of generic freeness only comes in the relative situation.

Comment: Bravo, Justin: this is a very elegant argument!